Exit handler never called! This is an error with npm itself
I am trying to run tests in the pipeline for a react application. Script looks as below:
Earlier the first three lines weren't there. I have tried running the command npm install with --force/--legacy-peer-deps options as well. No help.
I have also tried changing the node version and docker base image (FROM node:lts to FROM node:18.20.3-alpine3.20 a working version in an existing similar repo).
    script:
        - "npm cache clean --force"
        - "rm -rf node_modules"
        - "rm package-lock.json"
        - "npm install"
        - "npm test"

Below is the error log I am getting:

Below is the error I am getting after adding --force flag.
npm warn deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm error Exit handler never called!
npm error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm error   <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-19T15_10_34_356Z-debug-0.log


